# Switchable selectable text

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, text

I have a table which is filled with data from a database. Some javascript allows a user to select certain rows and take some actions. I allow users to click one row and then to shift click another row to create a group (as well as alt-click to select/deselect individual rows).

The problem is I don't like how the text highlights when they shift click. Is there some CSS setting or javascript/jQuery solution to disable the selectable text (cross browser preferablly or just in firefox).

If possible I also want to be able to let the user select text to copy and paste sometimes or inside a textbox form input inside the same table so I would like to be able to enable and disable the selecting of text somehow. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should do the trick:

```
$('td').disableSelection();
```

example:
http://jsfiddle.net/GhfuJ/1/

Comment: make sure you add jquery UI:https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.13/jquery-ui.min.js

Comment: Adding the entire jQueryUI library just for the `disableSelection` method?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way you could completely disable text selection:

```
$("selector").bind($.support.selectstart ? "selectstart" : "mousedown", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

This is how jQueryUI [implements its `disableSelection()` method](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/blob/master/ui/jquery.ui.core.js#L120).

You could tailor your selector to exclude `textarea` elements, or wrap code inside the event handler with an `if` block that evaluates a boolean that gets set under certain circumstances (For example, you could turn on booleans when the user is clicking or shift/alt + clicking).